# twitter bootstrap responsive menu hover

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap, hover, navbar

How to change the hover text-color of the menu/navbar into white when it is being viewed on mobile. I've tried looking into the css code of the bootstrap but i can't find it. [image: Screen]

Answer (score 2):

You can write media query to cater specific hover state for the `li` element like :
Jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/evX7x/1/)

```
  @media (max-width: 767px) {

.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
background-color: #888;/* change this color*/
box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125) inset;
color: #555555;
text-decoration: none;
  }
  } 
 @media (max-width: 767px) {

 .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover, .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:focus, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus {
 background-color: #000;/*you can change this color to anything*/
  }
 }
  @media (max-width: 480px) {

     .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover, .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:focus, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus {
 background-color: #000;/* you can change this color to anything */
}
}
```